# Obtener productos mas vendidos de la semana CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

tengo esta funcion en el Modelo, es sobre las ventas, pero esta hace referencia a la tabla detalle_venta, la cual contiene los productos que se vendieron, entonces lo que quisiera es saber como puedo formular la consulta para que me de los ultimos 5 productos mas vendidos, muchas gracias:

Consulta en el Modelo:

```
    public function productosmasVendidos(){
         $this->db->select("p.id, p.nombre, p.condicion, p.stock, p.precio,SUM(dv.cantidad) as totalVendidos");
         $this->db->from("detalle_venta dv");
         $this->db->join("productos p", "dv.producto_id = p.id");
         $this->db->join("ventas v", "dv.venta_id = v.id");
         $this->db->where("ACA NO SE QUE PONER");
         $this->db->group_by("dv.producto_id"); //esto no se si esta bien
         $resultados = $this->db->get();
         return $resultados->result();
}
```

Listo aca dejo el codigo del Modelo ya resuelto:

```
public function getProductosmasVendidos(){
    $this->db->select("p.id, p.codigo, p.nombre, p.condicion, p.stock, p.precio,SUM(dv.cantidad) as totalVendidos, c.nombre as categoria");
    $this->db->from("detalle_venta dv");
    $this->db->join("productos p", "dv.producto_id = p.id");
    $this->db->join("ventas v", "dv.venta_id = v.id");
    $this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
    $this->db->order_by("totalVendidos", "desc"); 
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $this->db->group_by("dv.producto_id");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Esto es el Controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array(
        'productosmvendidos' => $this->Ventas_model->getProductosmasVendidos(),
    );

    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/dashboard",$data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");

}
```

Y aca seria en la vista, dejo solo la parte del div donde estara la tabla:

```
<!--Productos mas vendidos-->
         <div style="background-color: white;" class="row">
                <div  class="col-md-12">
                    <div align="center">
                    <div calss="col-md-12 content-header"> <strong>Top 10 Productos mas Vendidos</strong></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive "></div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Codigo</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Categoria</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php if(!empty($productosmvendidos)):?>
                                <?php foreach($productosmvendidos as $pmv):?>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $pmv->codigo;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pmv->nombre;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pmv->categoria;?></td>

                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: No necesitas un `WHERE`, prueba algo así: `$this->db->order_by("totalVendidos", "desc");
$this->db->limit(5);`  de ese modo ordenas por `totalVendidos` en modo descendente y limitas los resultados a 5.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pude solventar mi problema, un saludo!

Comment: Deje el resto del proceso en la pregunta, por si le es de ayuda a alguien